# How to solve differential equation $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\lambda y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}\right)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My task is to solve for $y$ from:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\lambda y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}\right)=1$$

I have been given the answer, but I would like to calculate this myself also. $\lambda$ is a constant. How should I proceed?

The answer according to source material:

> Integrating with respect to $x$ we get:
>
> $$x+C_1= \lambda\sin(\theta)$$
>
> $$y=-\lambda\cos(\theta)+C_2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint:

integrating once you get $$\dfrac{y^\prime}{\sqrt{1+{y^\prime}^2}} = \dfrac{x + C}{\lambda}  \tag 1$$

(a) square $(1)$ and find $y^\prime$

(b) solve the first order equation.

---

edit:

since the left hand side of $(1)$ is smaller than one in absolute value, it can be set to $\sin \theta.$ which gives 
$$x + C = \sin \theta, \  \dfrac{y^\prime}{\sqrt{1+{y^\prime}^2}} = \sin \theta$$

solving the second equation  gives $y^\prime = \tan \theta.$ therefore

$$\frac{dy}{d \theta} = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{d \theta} = \tan \theta \cos \theta = \sin \theta$$ which has the solution $$y = \cos \theta + D$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! =)I tried this by myself and I got a solution in terms of $x$. I will post it below, maybe you could check it? =)

Comment: Hi @abel I posted my attempt..what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own try:

$$\frac{\lambda y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=x+C$$

$$\frac{ y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=\frac{x+C}{\lambda}$$

$$\frac{y'^2}{1+y'^2}=\frac{\left(x+C\right)^2}{\lambda^2}$$

$$\frac{-1}{1+y'^2}=\frac{\left(x+C\right)^2-\lambda^2}{\lambda^2}$$

$$1+y'^2=\frac{-\lambda^2}{\left(x+C\right)^2-\lambda^2}$$

$$y'^2=\frac{-\left(x+C\right)^2}{\left(x+C\right)^2-\lambda^2}$$

$$y'^2=\frac{\left(x+C\right)^2}{\lambda^2-\left(x+C\right)^2}$$

$$\int \;dy=\pm\int \frac{x+C}{\sqrt{\lambda^2-\left(x+C\right)^2}}\;dx$$

$$u=x+C,\;du=dx$$

$$y = \int \;dy=\pm \int \frac{u}{\sqrt{\lambda^2-u^2}}\;du = \pm \;-\sqrt{\lambda^2-u^2}+D=\pm\sqrt{\lambda^2-\left(x+C\right)^2}+D$$

so

$$y(x)=\pm \sqrt{\lambda^2-\left(x+C\right)^2}+D$$

Comment: well done. the solution you have in the question is too cute. not easy to come up with it. this is what you will get if you eliminate the $\theta$ between $y$ and $x$ in your question.

Comment: Thank you @abel for your help =) Nice to hear that. Yes it was difficult for me to understand the solution in my reference =)